# Error of infinite recursion in R(Shiny)

Tags: r, recursion, shiny, shiny-server

I am working on R(Shiny) that is working on a loan prediction model. I am trying to calculate loan amount for a particular method but it is showing me an error for infinite recursion and just like mentioned in most of the posts even I have tried **options(expressions = 1000)** value, but am still experiencing the error.

If I write my condition as

```
MDBB_LA<- reactive({ input$MDBB*10 })
```

then it is giving me no error but if I add another condition on this as

```
 DSCR_Post<- reactive({
 if (input$MU == "EMM" & (input$EMIM/12)+EMI()!=0) {
  EBITDA_EMM()/((input$EMIM/12) + EMI())
} else if (input$MU == "EMM" & (input$EMIM/12)+EMI()==0) {
  0
} else if (input$MU != "EMM" & (input$EMIM/12)+EMI()!=0 ){
  EBITDA()/((input$EMIM/12) + EMI())
}else{
  0
}})

  MDBB_LA<- reactive({ if ((input$MU == "EMM" & DSCR_Post() >= 1) | (input$MU == "FAT1" & DSCR_Post() >= 0.8) | (input$MU == "FAT2" & DSCR_Post() >= 0.7) | (input$MU == "UAT" & DSCR_Post() >= 0.5)) {
  input$MDBB*10*2
} else if ((input$MU == "EMM" & DSCR_Post() < 1) | (input$MU == "FAT1" & DSCR_Post() < 0.8 ) | (input$MU == "FAT2" & DSCR_Post() < 0.7) | (input$MU == "UAT" & DSCR_Post() < 0.5)){
  input$MDBB*10
} else if ((input$MU == "MDBB1" ) | (input$MU == "MDBB2" ) | (input$MU == "MDBB3") | (input$MU == "MDBB4") ){
  input$MDBB*10
} else {input$MDBB*10}
})
```

then it is showing me error as :

> Warning: Error in : evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?

Anyone who can help me, what is going wrong with the logical statement.

Comment: What does `DSCR_Post()` look like??

Comment: Can you give a reproductible exemple ? And why do you have three distinct conditions for the same result `input$MDBB*10` ? You can have just one global else, no ?

Comment: DSCR_Post() is a function I am defining which is performing some calculations

Comment: I have tried with just if and else condition but still it is giving me the same error

Comment: could you please supply a MWE of your complete app displaying your problem

Comment: What happens when you remove all calls of `DSCR_Post()`

Comment: then it is throwing reult

Comment: The error means that you're calling a reactive object within itself.

Comment: so how can I make a function in Shiny without using reactivity so that I can use its value further in another function

Comment: @Phil I am not able to understand what does it mean to call a reactive object within itself?

Comment: It means that you're referring to something within `DSCR_Post()` - could be `EMI()`, `EBITDA_EMM()`, or `EBITDA()` that is being defined by `DSCR_POST()`, causing an infinite loop. I would look at each step of your code, and comment out the other steps to pinpoint where the error is occurring.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by 'being defined by DSCR_POST()'. Can you explain it in more detail and yes EBITDA() and EBITDA_EMM() are getting used in DSCR_Post()

Comment: I meant the other way around - Is `DSCR_Post()` used to define those other reactive objects? If so, that is your problem. You're creating a logical impasse because A is being defined by B, while B is being defined by A.

Comment: I have checked the variables: EBITDA_EMM() EBITDA() EMIP(), these are the variables which are being used in calculating DSCR_Post() but these variables are not using DSCR_Post() calculation.

Answer (score 0):

This is tough to answer without a reproducible answer, but the two ways I know of to get around this issue, without adjusting the code or your data, are to increase the expressions and the ppsize. Try going above 1000, like 1500 or 2000 for the expressions (or even 20000). Also try increasing the --max-ppsize when you open your console.

Comment: I think it's probably because I am using the method  DSCR_Post and then calling it. So method is being called multiple times